# Resource ownership of GetObjectResponse.InputStream

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

Who owns the OCI object-storage GetObjectResponse.InputStream resource?

Do I need to explicitly close the stream? There is no information about this in the API doc.

Comment: Yep, it's just a Java InputStream so you should close it after reading from it. [This example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstream.html) might help.

Comment: My question is about the ownership of the inputStream. Do you meant to say ownership of GetObjectResponse.InputStream is with the caller?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes. You're basically just getting a resource that let's you read data from somewhere, so you're "owning" that part of the connection that needs to be opened and closed on your end.

Answer (score 1):

As Char stated, the InputStream is "owned" by you, requiring you to open/close it.